# Let a variable equal multiple values in an if-statement

Tags: if-statement, stata, recode

I am doing data clean-up in Stata and I need to recode a variable to equal `1` if a whole set of other variables are equal to `1`, `6`, or `7`.

I can do this using the code below:

```
replace anyadl = 1 if diffdress==1 | diffdress==6 | diffdress==7 | ///
                      diffwalk==1  | diffwalk==6  | diffwalk==7  | ///
                      diffbath==1  | diffbath==6  | diffbath==7  | ///
                      diffeat==1   | diffeat==6   | diffeat==7   | ///
                      diffbed==1   | diffbed==6   | diffbed==7   | /// 
                      difftoi==1   | difftoi==6   | difftoi==7
```

However, this is very inefficient to type out and it is easy to make errors.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

For example, something along the following lines:

```
replace anyadl = 1 if diff* == (1 | 6 | 7)
```

Comment: Your wording and your code clash. Your code implies that any of these variables being 1, 6, 7 is fine. "a whole set of other variables" implies that all of them are. I have gone for what your code implies.

Comment: Your syntax is not using an `if` statement, but an `if` qualifier,

Comment: Your name starting `any` I also took as indicating your real intent,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fantasy syntax wouldn't do what you want even if it were legal, as for example `1|6|7` would be evaluated as 1. That is, in Stata 1 OR 6 OR 7 is in effect true OR true OR true, so true, and thus 1, given the rules non-zero is true as input and true is 1 as output. The expression is `1|6|7` is legal; it's the wildcard in an equality or inequality that isn't.

Stepping back, your code is producing an indicator (some people say dummy) variable with values 1 or missing. In practice such a variable is much more useful if created with values 0 and 1 (and in some instances missing too).

```
generate anyad1 = 0 

foreach v in dress walk bath eat bed toi { 
    replace anyad1 = 1 if inlist(diff`v', 1, 6, 7) 
}
```

is one approach. In general, note both `inlist(foo, 1, 6, 7)` and `inlist(1, foo, bar, bazz)` as useful constructs.

Reading:

[This paper on generating indicators](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099)

[This one on useful functions](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0058)

[This one on `inlist()` and `inrange()`](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0026)

[FAQ on true and false in Stata](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/)

Comment: Thank you!  The inlist function is exactly what I was looking for, and I was not previously familiar with it.  (FYI, I know that I need to also designate what produces zero and missing values for my dummy variable -- I just limited my code to the part I had a question about in order to simplify the question.)